# Random Variable Distribution Example Problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

I have difficulty on answering this question, I have done a few research but it doesn't help me to do this question. This is probability question, and I don't know what kind of formula should I use to answer this question.

```
If 2/3 of the population of a large community is in favor of a proposed rise 
in school taxes, approximate the probability that a random sample of 72 people 
will contain
a.At least 50 who are in favor of the proposition?
b.Between 35 and 59 inclusive who are in favor?
```

Thank you guys for your help and kindness.

Comment: The fact that this concerns the population of a **large** community justifies to use binomial distribution here. At e.g. a) you are asked to find an expression for $P(X\geq50)$ where $X$ has [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n=72$ and $p=2/3$. If you also must calculate the expression then you can make use of the fact that the distribution can be approached by normal distribution equipped with parameters $\mu=np$ and $\sigma^2=np(1-p)$.

Comment: Thanks, bro, it is really helpful for me :).@drhab